# Can't find Spyder or Ipython Notebook applications after Anaconda install (xubuntu 13.10)

Tags: xubuntu, python, ipython, spyder

I installed Anaconda 2.7.  I can run spyder and ipython notebook from the terminal but I can't find the applications at all from the desktop.

Is there a specific place I should look?  Should I just reinstall?

I know they are there as they run from the terminal but I want to be able to put them on the desktop as well.

Answer (score 3):

there

I've faced the same problem on Ubuntu & Lubuntu

The *launcher* and *node-webkit* were not install along with the Anaconda 2.7 for linux package.

You can install it manually by

```
conda install -f launcher
conda install -f node-webkit
```

now you should be able to launch **'launcher'** app from **terminal** like Mac or Win.

Answer (score 1):

This is an updated answer for modern versions of [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) [4.4.0 as of 2017].

1. Make sure you have appended your `~/.bashrc` file with the following command:

   `export PATH="/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`

---

2. Check if you have `anaconda-navigator` installed by typing the same on a terminal. If not, use the following command to install `anaconda-navigator`.

   `conda install anaconda-navigator`

   To launch `anaconda-navigator`, just type the exact name on a terminal.

---

In order to install a desktop shortcut, create a file called `anaconda.desktop` and enter the following content within that file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Anaconda-Navigator
GenericName=Anaconda
Comment=Scientific PYthon Development EnviRonment - Python3
Exec=bash -c 'export PATH="/home/YOUR_USER_NAME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" && /home/YOUR_USER_NAME/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator'
Categories=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;Education;
Icon=spyder3
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/x-python;
```

---

Of course, it goes without saying that you have to edit the above commands with YOUR specific paths (e.g. `/home/ironman6788/anaconda/bin`).

Answer (score 0):

if you go in to the anaconda folder, you should see a little icon called "Launcher". I think that's what you're looking for